# foo(bar) and foo(bar, baz)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In ES6, is it possible to have some code like this:

```
class MyClass
{
     foo(bar)
     {
          console.log(bar + "Bar")
     }
     foo(bar, baz)
     {
          console.log(bar + baz + "Bar baz")
     }
}
```

so that when I did:

```
MyClass.foo("Hello, ", "World and ")
```

I would get:

```
Hello, World and Bar baz
```

And I would be able to do:

```
MyClass.foo("Hello, world!")
```

to get:

```
Hello, world!Bar
```

like in Java?

Comment: Just curious, did you try it?

Comment: method overloading isn't there. the second `foo` will just overwrite the first, but yes, did u try to run it?

Comment: I will try to and give results.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: MyClass.foo is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'd need the `static` keyword, just like in Java.

```
class MyClass
{
     static foo(bar)
     {
          console.log(bar + " World")
     }
}
MyClass.foo("Hello")
```

Second, JavaScript doesn't overload methods. It's arguably more flexible this way - you can just handle arguments yourself.

```
class MyClass
{
     static foo(bar, baz)
     {
          if (baz) {
             console.log(bar + baz + " World");
          } else {
             console.log(bar + " World");
          }
     }
}
MyClass.foo("Hello")
```

Comment: Thank you, I might try this out and see if I get my results I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters).

```
class MyClass
{
    static foo(bar, baz='')
    {
        console.log(bar + baz + "Bar" + (baz ? " baz" : ""));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that's not possible since when you call a function that accepts two arguments with only one argument, the second one would be set to undefined. Most js libraries do their own flavor of overloading by checking the types of the parameters passed, and in case this would be implemented, this would likely break those libraries.